# Spring Data + Redis with Auto increment Key

Tags: redis, spring-data

I am trying to do Spring data CRUD Operation with Redis but mainly I need to store the auto increment key in Redis.

I have tried the simple CRUD operation for SpringData with Redis but there is no auto increment key feature.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring data redis repository, you can annotate the field with `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` for which value needs to be auto generated and a `@RedisHash` annotation on its class.

```
@RedisHash("persons")
public class Person {

  @Id String id;
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  Address address;
}
```

To now actually have a component responsible for storage and retrieval you need to define a repository interface.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

}

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {

    RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]>();
    return template;
  }
}
```

Given the setup above you can go on and inject PersonRepository into your components.

```
@Autowired PersonRepository repo;

public void basicCrudOperations() {

  Person rand = new Person("rand", "al'thor");
  rand.setAddress(new Address("emond's field", "andor"));

  repo.save(rand);               //1                          

  repo.findOne(rand.getId());    //2                          

  repo.count();                  //3                          

  repo.delete(rand);             //4                          
}
```

1. Generates a new id if current value is null or reuses an already set id value and stores properties of type Person inside the Redis Hash with key with pattern keyspace:id in this case eg. persons:5d67b7e1-8640-4475-beeb-c666fab4c0e5.
2. Uses the provided id to retrieve the object stored at keyspace:id.
3. Counts the total number of entities available within the keyspace persons defined by @RedisHash on Person.
4. Removes the key for the given object from Redis.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks For Answering...As per above It will giving me Id like - 5d67b7e1-8640-4475-beeb-c666fab4c0e5 but what I am expecting to Auto increment Id Like 1,2,3,4...in radis.Here the Id You have mention above seemes like Unique Key not a Incremented Key.