# Autoincrement with Long in Redis using Spring Data Repository?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I went through the link : [Spring Data + Redis with Auto increment Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341864/spring-data-redis-with-auto-increment-key), but I am using PK as `Long` in `Redis`. How we can do `Autoincrement` of `ids` in Redis ?

Group.java

```
@RedisHash("groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    private Long groupId;
    private String name;
}
```

User.java

```
@RedisHash("users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate createdDate;
}
```

What's the recommanded approach here? Any quick pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not `auto-increment` features in Redis even if you used `Long` as `Id`. Simply used the String as `Id` and annotate it with `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` i.e `@Id` and apply `@Indexed` at the Model class and you should be simply able to get or search the hash in redis.

It works well and you dont need to take care of Auto-increment etc. Just leave upto Redis to create it for you.